# SQL MAX and total of by date and product

Tags: sql

Help needed - I need to get from the table the percent of the top contributing page of each day out of all the days.
I need to show it by date, page, % of total subscription on that date, % of total all time

here is the table :

```
P_date |    PageName | Subscribes
02/05/2020  page1   258
05/05/2020  page1   10 
01/07/2020  page1   236
02/05/2020  page2   15
02/05/2020  page3   14
05/05/2020  page2   13
05/05/2020  page3   223
```

Here is my code :

```
select P_date,  
    max(total_subs) as Max_subs, 
    format((max(total_subs)/sum(total_subs)),'.00%') as 'Percentage out of total that day',
    format((max(total_subs) / (select sum(total_subs) from 
    table1)),'.00%') as  'Percentage out of total'  from table1
group by P_date order by 'Percentage out of total' desc
```

The output is:

[image]

But I need to add also the pagename - I need to show 1 best page per day?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (BTW, most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.)

Comment: You can do it using window functions, please provide the data in text format and specify the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions as follows:

```
select p_date, page_name, total_subs, 1
    1.0 * total_subs / total_subs percentage_day, 
    1.0 * total_subs / sum_total_subs percentage_overall
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by p_date order by total_subs desc) rn
        sum(total_subs) over(partition by p_date) p_date_total_subs,
        sum(total_subs) over() overal_total_subs 
    from table1 t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can do:

```
SELECT * /*specify desired columns here*/
( 
  SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT table1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P_date ORDER BY Subscribes DESC) as row_num
    FROM table1 )
  WHERE row_num = 1
) as bestPagePerDate
JOIN (
select P_date,  
    max(total_subs) as Max_subs, 
    format((max(total_subs)/sum(total_subs)),'.00%') as 'Percentage out of total that day',
    format((max(total_subs) / (select sum(total_subs) from 
    table1)),'.00%') as  'Percentage out of total'  from table1
group by P_date order by 'Percentage out of total' desc
) as yourQuery
ON yourQuery.P_date = bestPagePerDate.P_date
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a subquery with the query of the best page per day and show it in your global query.